# Normals Problem

Tags: normals

I extruded the skirt of the character i am making on two different places to have a riplled part and another part underneath the top part of the skirt.
For that to work i needed to flip the normals on the top part but now it looks like there is a bump in the skirt where the connections with the other skirt parts are.
If i delete the connections everything looks fine but i want to have the connections with the skirt and dont know what i have to do with the normals for it to work can somebody help me?

[image: Normal problem at the cut]

[image]

Comment: Looking at the edge of the model it seems to me the geometry is just uneven. Could you post the wire frame?

Comment: i added a picture of the wireframe i hope you can see something on it